# bash config file from remote source with an argument

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which works like this;

```
.
├── script.sh
├── configs
|   ├── conf1.conf
|   └── conf2.conf
```

`script.sh`;

```
#!/bin/bash

function test {
  echo $var1
}

case $1 in
  $1) cfg=$1 ;;
esac

cfg_file=~/config/"$cfg.conf" 

if [ -f "$cfg_file" ]; then
  . "$cfg_file"
  test $1
else
  echo "$1.conf doesn't exist"
  exit 1
fi
```

`conf1.conf`;

```
var1=test1
```

`conf2.conf`;

```
var1=test2
```

So in this script, if you run `./script.sh conf1` then it will use the `conf1.conf` file and will print `test1` from `var1` to shell. Same apply for `conf2` and so on.

I'm trying to change the source of the config files to a remote source like this;

`cfg_file='http://example.com/configs/"$cfg.conf"'`

I've tried this very code above but it couldn't locate the config file.

How can I do this in bash, if possible?

Comment: Don't call your own function `test`, it clashes with the built-in.

Comment: Thank for the heads up

Comment: The duplicate is not 100% but you should easily be able to adapt it. Also tangentially, fix your quoting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: I've checked that question but it's asking to run a bash script itself from a url. My bash script is running locally and I'm only trying to fetch config files remotely, not the script itself.

Comment: The answer is still that Bash has no built-in HTTP client; use `curl` or `wget`